# Ansible reporting "CHANGED" on "hostname"?

Tags: ansible, exit-status

According to Ansible's own [documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/common_return_values.html#changed):

> changed:
>   A boolean indicating if the task had to make changes.

Why then does a command to report hostname return a "changed" status?

```
localhost:/Users/me/VMs $:ansible multi -a "hostname" -f 1

192.168.60.4 | CHANGED | rc=0 >>
orc-app1.test

192.168.60.5 | CHANGED | rc=0 >>
orc-app2.test

192.168.60.6 | CHANGED | rc=0 >>
orc-db.test
```

Answer (score 2):

You aren't running the `hostname` module, though. In fact, you haven't specified a module at all. [`-a` sets the *argument* for a module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/cli/ansible.html#cmdoption-ansible-a), not the module itself (that's [`-m`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/cli/ansible.html#cmdoption-ansible-module-name)). The default module is the [command](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/command_module.html#command-module) module, and the command (and shell, and similar modules) always have a status of changed if they ran successfully (because Ansible doesn't know how to track what changes could have been made by some arbitrary command).